# Flutter / Android 12 - Using deep links to open app default but it opens browser by default

Tags: flutter, dart, android-12

```
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="flutterbooksample.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Using deep links to open app default but it opens browser default

In Android 11 or less it works what we expected
In Android 12 it only opens browser as default

Answer (score 2):

If your deep link URL looks like `https://abc.page.link/services`
where `services` is the deep-lined page

Change `<data android:host="example.host"/>` to `<data android:host="abc.page.link"/>`

Make sure to restart the app.

Comment: No, it doesn't help me

Comment: any errors in terminal/debug console? What does your dynamic link look like?

Comment: try `<data android:host="*.page.link"/>`

Comment: This is an exact issue In Android 11 or less it works what we expected but when it comes Android 12 or higher it only opens browser as default

Comment: check this, `Web Links` in android 11 and earlier opens your app by default, but opens in browser Android 12+. https://developer.android.com/training/app-links#add-app-links

Comment: I have tried with these links

Comment: To reproduce this issue 

1.Replace code in mainfest file
   

<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <data android:host="flutterbooksample.com"/>
        </intent-filter>

Comment: open android simulator with Version 12+

Comment: run this command adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://flutterbooksample.com/"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251383/discussion-between-delwinn-and-pradeepkumar).